# Should I re-install GRUB when installing new linux distro?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I already have Windows 8.1 Pro and Ubuntu running on my system. When I boot, I use the Grub bootloader to select my operating system. I'm planning to install a new Linux distro (kali 2.0), if on the setup it prompts me to install GRUB, should I install Grub again?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in installing Grub again.

Infact **it will automatically detect previous installations**, i.e.:

1. Kali Linux
2. Ubuntu
3. Windows 8 loader

and make all entries available in grub.

Comment: Yes grub "DESIGN"(pink color) will be replaced by kali's grub "DESIGN" (black), but entries will show up. Moreover you can always reinstall UBUNTU's  grub again by from Ubuntu installation or Ubuntu Live USB : http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd